# Android Reusing layout in landscape and portrait

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape-portrait

is it possible to pass parameters to a included layout in android? What i would like to do for example is to display a set of buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout when in landscape mode, and to use the same include to change the orientation of the LinearLayout to "vertical".

```
<include layout="buttons.xml" orientation="horizontal"/>
```

In the layout XML used for portrait mode I would like to do:

```
<include layout="buttons.xml" orientation="vertical"/>
```

And in buttons.xml I would have:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doSomething"
        android:text="foo" >
    </Button>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="doSomethingElse"
        android:text="bar" >
    </Button>
```

If I interpret the docs correctly it's only possible to override the layout* attributes of the include.

Is there an other way/workaround to do that without duplicating the layout xml?
Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit late but here is another possibility without splitting the layout: you may also set the orientation value of the LinearLayout in an xml-file. Since the orientation values are **integers** (0: horizontal, 1: vertical) you may also use this way:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="@integer/orientation" >
```

And then set/override this orientation value in xml-files:

**dimens.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="orientation">1</integer>   <!-- vertical //-->
</resources>
```

**dimens-land.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <integer name="orientation">0</integer>   <!-- horizontal //-->
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

Android deals with this by providing diferent folders for the diferent configurations.

From documentation:

> As another example, here's a project with an alternative layout for landscape orientation:
>
> MyProject/
>
> res/
>         layout/
>
> ```
>        main.xml
>
>    layout-land/
>
>        main.xml
> ```
>
> By default, the layout/main.xml file is used for portrait orientation.

I belive you should do it like that since it's the way recommended in docummentation, but you can change the orientation yourseft if you decide to [control orientation changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange).

And use this to change the layout orientation:

```
LinearLayout layout = (get layout from view);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

or

```
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

Comment: Hi Mikel, changing the layout dynamically in code wasn't what I was thinking of. I was looking for a way to do it in xml. I am aware of the resource selectors to override a particular layout resource but I am concerned that using the selectors always produces redundant resources which are painful to maintain later on. Any other idea/tip?

Answer (score 0):

okay what I did in the end was to split my layout into 3 parts:

button_container.xml simply contains a LinearLayout and two additional includes

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="**horizontal**" >

   <include layout="@layout/button_top_row" />
   <include layout="@layout/button_bottom_row" />

</LinearLayout>
```

- button_row_top contains the buttons that should go in the top row (in handheld port view)

-button_row_bottom contains the buttons that should go in the bottom row (again in handheld port view)

button_container.xml exists in two versions one with orientation horizontal (for tablets, and landsacpe oriented mobile handhelds) and a version with orientation vertical (for handheld port).
So I managed to somehow minimise code douplication even though it isn't as easy as I would like it to be.

Any additional tips welcome.
Bye,
Markus